# ZSH with iTerm2 theme not configuring properly - no such file or directory

Tags: unix, terminal, zsh, iterm, oh-my-zsh

I want to install this [ZSH theme](https://github.com/wesbos/Cobalt2-iterm) . I downloaded both the iTerm2 and ZSH themes.

I have followed the step-by-step installation guide.

When I open my iTerm2 windows I see:

```
/Users/username/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:source:96: no such file or directory: /Users/username/.oh-my-zsh/themes/“cobalt2”.zsh-theme
~%
```

Here are more details:

```
~% echo $ZSH_THEME
“cobalt2”

~% echo $PROMPT
%n@%m:%~%#
```

In the `~/.zschrc` file is this:

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=/Users/username/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
ZSH_THEME=“cobalt2”

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# The optional three formats: "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)

# User configuration

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# ssh
# export SSH_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/dsa_id"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
```

Note: The `cobalt2.zsh-theme` file does exist in `~% ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes` but it is highlighted in read when `ls`

I did ask [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574084/why-cant-i-get-the-cobalt2-zsh-theme-to-work-on-my-iterm2), but this issue is on a different machine.

Answer (score 3):

I also got this error recently when i was installing a theme in iterm2

In your `.zshrc` file where you set the name of the theme don't include quotation marks. So instead of doing

```
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
```

you should do the following

```
ZSH_THEME=robbyrussell
```

This will solve your problem of getting a error when opeing a new tabs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're using smart quotes:

```
ZSH_THEME=“cobalt2”
```

You should be using regular quotes:

```
ZSH_THEME="cobalt2"
```